# Does neo4j auto index work for MATCH clause?

Tags: lucene, neo4j

We have turned on auto indexing for both nodes and relationship. By default NEO4J will create an index named "node_auto_index" for nodes and "relationship_auto_index" for relationships. But the MATCH queries seem to be under performing (comparing to a similar data set in Elasticsearch). Looks like they are not using the indexes.

Is there a way to make the MATCH clause use the auto_index ?

We also tried looking at the schema index. Looks like it can only create node indexes. Our queries use some properties on relationships and hence even after using the schema index the queries are unacceptable in performance. 
Is there a way to create schema relationship indexes ?

Comment: Can you update your post and include the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node_auto_index is not used for match, you would have to use the start clause to access that legacy index.

e.g.

```
START user=node:node_auto_index(name="Siddarth")
MATCH (user)-[:KNOWS]->(friend)
RETURN friend
```

In Neo4j 2.0 you can create an index or unique constraint instead

```
create index on :User(name);
```

and then use it in MATCH

```
MATCH (user:User {name:"Siddarth"})-[:FRIEND]->(friend)
RETURN friend
```

See also the manual: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-schema-index.html 
and the cypher refcard: http://neo4j.org/resources/cypher

Comment: I tried the following :

Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337
`neo4j-sh (?)$ schema

Indexes
 ON :order(scheduleDate) ONLINE
  No constraints

neo4j-sh (?)$ start n = node:order("scheduleDate:54647") return n;
          
MissingIndexException: Index `order` does not exist`

So while the schema command shows that the index is available, the start clause cannot find that index. Is it that the start clause can only work with auto indexes and not schema index ?

Comment: Start clause can only work with auto index. It does not work with schema indexes. I tried out with examples and found that to be true.